# How to cross out text of a checkbox via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

My code is:

```
$(function(){

    $('input:checkbox').on('change','span',function(){
        var input= $(this).find('span');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            //alert($(this).name);
            $(input).css('textDecoration','line-through');
        }else{
            $(input).css('textDecoration','none');
        }

    })
})
```

This is my HTML

```
 <div><input  type="checkbox" id="a1"></input><span>This is ok</span></div><br/>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="a2" ></input><span>This is yes</span></div>
```

But it is not working. I guess I am not getting the input properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to target the checkbox element for the change handler, then the span is the next sibling

```
$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
        var input = $(this).next('span');
        if (this.checked) {
            $(input).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
        } else {
            $(input).css('textDecoration', 'none');
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7eh9G/)

---

If you want event delegation

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox', function () {
        var input = $(this).next('span');
        if (this.checked) {
            $(input).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
        } else {
            $(input).css('textDecoration', 'none');
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7eh9G/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('change','input:checkbox',function() {
   var input= $(this).closest('span');
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).siblings('span').css('text-decoration','line-through');
    }else{
        $(this).siblings('span').css('text-decoration','none');
    }
});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMd4X/)